# live plotting using pyserial and matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pyserial

I can capture data from serial device via pyserial, at this time I can only export data to text file, the text file has format like below, it's have 3 columns

```
>21 21 0 
>
>41 41 0.5
>
>73 73 1
>    
....
>2053 2053 5
>
>2084 2084 5.5
>
>2125 2125 6
```

Now I want to use matplotlib to generate **live** graph has 2 figure (x,y) x,y are second and third column, first comlumn,'>', and lines don't have data can be remove

thank folks!

============================

Update : today, after follow these guides from

http://www.blendedtechnologies.com/realtime-plot-of-arduino-serial-data-using-python/231
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis
[pyserial - How to read the last line sent from a serial device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093598/pyserial-how-to-read-last-line-sent-from-serial-device)

now I can live plot with threading but eliben said that this Guis only plot single value each time, that lead to me the very big limitation, beacause my purpose is plotting 2 or 3 column, here is the code was modified from blendedtechnologies

Here is serial handler :
from threading import Thread

```
import time
import serial

last_received = ''
def receiving(ser):
    global last_received
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        buffer = buffer + ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if '\n' in buffer:
            lines = buffer.split('\n') # Guaranteed to have at least 2 entries
            last_received = lines[-2]
            #If the Arduino sends lots of empty lines, you'll lose the
            #last filled line, so you could make the above statement conditional
            #like so: if lines[-2]: last_received = lines[-2]
            buffer = lines[-1]


class SerialData(object):
    def __init__(self, init=50):
        try:
            self.ser = ser = serial.Serial(
                port='/dev/ttyS0',
                baudrate=9600,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                timeout=0.1,
                xonxoff=0,
                rtscts=0,
                interCharTimeout=None
            )
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            #no serial connection
            self.ser = None
        else:
            Thread(target=receiving, args=(self.ser,)).start()

    def next(self):
        if not self.ser:
            return 100  #return anything so we can test when Arduino isn't connected
                #return a float value or try a few times until we get one
        for i in range(40):
            raw_line = last_received[1:].split(' ').pop(0)
            try:
                return float(raw_line.strip())
            except ValueError:
                print 'bogus data',raw_line
                time.sleep(.005)
        return 0.
    def __del__(self):
        if self.ser:
            self.ser.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    s = SerialData()
    for i in range(500):
        time.sleep(.015)
        print s.next()
```

For me I modified this segment so it can grab my 1st column data

```
for i in range(40):
                raw_line = last_received[1:].split(' ').pop(0)
                try:
                    return float(raw_line.strip())
                except ValueError:
                    print 'bogus data',raw_line
                    time.sleep(.005)
            return 0.
```

and generate graph base on these function on the GUI file

```
from Arduino_Monitor import SerialData as DataGen
def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title)

        self.datagen = DataGen()
        self.data = [self.datagen.next()]
```

................................................

```
def init_plot(self):
        self.dpi = 100
        self.fig = Figure((3.0, 3.0), dpi=self.dpi)

        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_axis_bgcolor('black')
        self.axes.set_title('Arduino Serial Data', size=12)

        pylab.setp(self.axes.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
        pylab.setp(self.axes.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)

        # plot the data as a line series, and save the reference 
        # to the plotted line series
        #
        self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
            self.data, 
            linewidth=1,
            color=(1, 1, 0),
            )[0]
```

So my next question is how to realtime grab at least 2 column and passing 2 columns'data to the GUIs that it can generate graph with 2 axis.

```
self.plot_data.set_xdata(np.arange(len(self.data)))  #my 3rd column data
self.plot_data.set_ydata(np.array(self.data))        #my 2nd column data
```

Comment: So, what do you have so far? Let's break it down in a few steps. 1: can you extract the numbers from the text? 2: can you plot the numbers? 3: can you make the graph update with incoming data? --- Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you Daan for make me clear, at this time, I only capture the number from the device, next step I really concern on how to extract the number in the format that I can make plot later, can you suggest me on how to do that?

Comment: I currently use Ubuntu, pyserial, wxpython for this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this reads your string and converts the numbers to floats. I assume you'll be able to adapt this as needed.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

str = '''>21 21 0 
>
>41 41 0.5
>
>73 73 1
>
>2053 2053 5
>
>2084 2084 5.5
>
>2125 2125 6'''
nums = np.array([[float(n) for n in sub[1:].split(' ') if len(n)>0] for sub in str.splitlines() if len(sub)>1])

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax.plot(nums[:,0], nums[:,1], 'k.')
ax = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ax.plot(nums[:,0], nums[:,2], 'r+')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Daan, very nice, it work smooth, thank you so much, can you explain to me how you extract the data to nums array ? Can you show me how to update the plot in real time, thank you in advance

Comment: now I understand how you extract the data to the array! Can you show me how to update the plot in real time when pyserial capturing the data, thank you in advance

Comment: I think that has been covered extensively by other questions&answers on stackoverflow and the matplotlib cookbook. A quick search turns up several possible solutions. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Daan, you're so kind, I follow this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093598/pyserial-how-to-read-last-line-sent-from-serial-device and now I can plot but just only 1 column, I prefer your example bcs. it can pass 2 value so can plot 2 column at same time, can you suggest me how to plot 2 column at the same with threading in realtime.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with a minimal example of your code? It seems to me that if you have all the separate components working (getting the data, plotting some data, updating a graph) you should be able to combine those parts by yourself. If not, can you please show us where exactly in the process things go wrong?

Comment: hi Daan, wish you have a nice day, I've already updated my question, could you give me your comments and ideas, thank you so much

Comment: I guess your SerialData object should return not just the first column, but also the other numbers you want. Could it be this: raw_line = last_received[1:].split(' ').pop(0) is the culprit? I guess if you don't pop(), you get all three numbers.

Comment: hi Daan, you're right, but I use the pop because the plot function can only accept value from 1 column,now the last step for me is how to make the plot function draw 2 column at same time!

Comment: hi Dann, the SerialData Object return 3 column default for me, but I can not draw from 2 column I need to modify this function self.plot_data.set_xdata(np.arange(len(self.data)))
        self.plot_data.set_ydata(np.array(self.data)) but I don't know how to write code to isolate data from the serialdata return, could you give me some advise?

Comment: if np.array(self.data) is an array of shape (3,N) then you could select a column via np.array(self.data)[0,:] (or [1,:], or [2,:]).

Comment: hi Dann, after these lines 
raw_line = last_received[1:]
    try:
       return float(raw_line.strip())

and self.plot_data.set_ydata(np.array(self.data)[0,:]) it return an Index error: too many indices 

honestly I really don't know what its data return ?_? the hardest part for me now is to seperate to your format

Comment: What type is self.data? What shape is np.array(self.data)? Does self.data contain what you expect it to contain? How about you add a few print statements throughout your code and check what happens to your variables as your script runs?

Comment: self.data is in list type and it have only one value inside [0.0], np.array(self.data) also have one value [0.] I think because of the float() function in the return, I think it should be return the object not the list with one value

Comment: Well, if there is only one value in self.data, then obviously you can't extract multiple values from it. Are you still using this: raw_line = last_received[1:].split(' ').pop(0)? Because I think that's where you are reducing your input to a single value. Can you get to a point where raw_line contains several values and not just one?

Comment: no I use only raw_line = last_received[1:]
            try:
                return float(raw_line.strip())
                #return float(torque)
            except ValueError:
                print 'bogus data',raw_line

and it return to me like this bogus data 361 361 0

Comment: how about raw_line = last_received[1:].split() (so you split your string at the spaces and get three strings) and then: return [float(k) for k in raw_line] (so you get the float for every string in your list of strings).

Comment: my god it return self.data [[-481.0, -481.0, 0.0 ]]

Answer (score 1):

[Here you have](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/07/a-live-data-monitor-with-python-pyqt-and-pyserial/) an Eli Bendersky's example of how plotting data arriving from a serial port

Comment: thank you joaquin, I'm reading that and will dig into the code, I use the wxpython for this project

Comment: @billyduc I do not understand what you mean with "I use wxpython". Your question indicates matplotlib + pyserial. Is that right?. In case you are **also** using wxPython for your program GUI probably you know that you can embed the matplotlib figure in a wxPython window. Dont forget to upvote the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: hi @joaquin, I really want to vote up, but I need more than 15 reputations, I just new to stackoverflow :D, btw thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

some time back I had the same problem. I wasted a lot of writing same ting over and over again. so I wrote a python package for it.

https://github.com/girish946/plot-cat

you just have to write the logic for obtaining the data from serial port.

the example is here: https://github.com/girish946/plot-cat/blob/master/examples/test-ser.py