# How to live Plot new value base on capture pyserial data

Tags: wxpython, matplotlib, pyserial

This question is the next question of this one [live plotting using pyserial and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265938/live-plotting-using-pyserial-and-matplotlib)

Now I can live plot the data but I want my plot must start to plot from y = 0, for example

```
var_y from device begin with 300, y = 0
var_y = 500 -> y = 200
var_y = 700 -> y = 400
and so on
```

This is my var_y variable capture using pyserial

```
self.var_y = np.array(self.data,dtype=object)[:,1]
```

no matter how var_y changes, my plot must alway start from y = 0

Answer (score 0):

take a look in the function ylim().
in your case you should use:

```
ax.set_ylim(0,someMaxValue)
```

this should be set everytime before you call

```
plt.show().
```