# Python : How to make a script enter and exit minicom terminal?

Tags: python, linux, bash, loops, subprocess

For entering minicom and saving the log of it, I use "sudo minicom -C nameoffile", but I want to do this in a loop, opening minicom can be done by using subprocess but I couldn't find anything to exit minicom in my loop and continue looping, since you need to enter "ctrl-a, then x" or "ctrl-a, then q" and after must press enter for confirming this. Anybody have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: For how long do you wish to run the minicom? How about running it as a sub-process and killing from outside (from the father process)?

Comment: @ArnonZilca thank you for your comment and sorry for late answer, but will it be able to run again after I kill it? I need to run the loop for at least an hour and minicom must be logged, grepped and the line will be appended to a list then it must be shut, after same routine must go.

Comment: Do you **want** to run-it, kill-it, run-it, kill-it... or do you want to run it the whole time and sample it from time to time. Does the configuration or the device changes from one sample to another?

Comment: @ArnonZilca yes, I want to run-it, kill-it and make it in a loop, because I think if I run it whole time I won't be able to use Bash to gather "iwlist output data" or NMEA sentences

Comment: @ArnonZilca No, once it is connected, it is always seen as ttyUSB1,ttyUSB2 and ttyUSB3, the one I use for gathering data for that device is ttyUSB3 and I setup and save ttyUSB3 to minicom.

Comment: Got it. I'll write my response as an answer.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe instead of using minicom, use a Python library such as [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to directly access the serial port.

Comment: @TolgaVarol I agree with Andre. And as you can see I answered for X rather than Y.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The first (and obvious) solution

might take a little more effort (or not - you decide) and it is probably the **best** way to do this is to [open the device yourself using pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) ([and here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093598/pyserial-how-to-read-the-last-line-sent-from-a-serial-device)) and then do whatever you like with the data - write it to a file, parse it, send it to NASA or all of the above. :)

If you insist on working around that solution:

#### One possibility I can think of...

is piping the minicom command to `tee`. when you pipe through `tee` you can give it a file name (to log to) and pipe `tee` as input to your own binary / script. That should take care of logging + parsing the input. (I Haven't tried it with minicom and i'm not sure how you will exit your piped program like that).

#### Another possibility I can think of...

is redirect to a file (`>`) and then write a different binary / script that will read the file as it is being written (like `tail -f` does).
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290292/read-from-a-log-file-as-its-being-written-using-python) an example for reading a file in python while it is being written.

Since it's serial data, I'm guessing it's pretty slow (especially NMEA), so I don't think that you will have much latency if you write it to a file and read it using a different binary / script.

Comment: IF there is no need to use minicom, using `pyserial` is far easier. So +1 for the first suggestion. File write latency problems come with buffering, fast data is actually easier than slow data.

Comment: @DrV minicom is needed, because I can't send AT commands from python script directly.

Comment: @Arnon Zilca , thank you for your answer, I just wrote a code for reading via pyserial but it is not reading the AT commands, it is just reading an "A" from the 3G module.                          _ser3g = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB3", 115200, timeout = 5)_
    **time.sleep(1)**
    _ser3g.write("AT+CSQ")_
    **time.sleep(1)**
    _response = ser3g.read()_
    **print >> file ,date,',',val[:42],',',data,',',response**

Comment: @Arnon Zilca , only thing comes to my mind now is to capture minicom terminal inside the loop but I don't have any idea how to exit minicom inside a loop like run it- kill it- run it.... and so on. For capturing what I do is **'sudo' 'minicom' '-C' 'filename'** , do you have any idea how I can exit minicom terminal in a loop?

Comment: Both of the solutions (other than pySerial), suggest you do it without run-kill-run-kill. I think that piping minicom to tee and then to a parser python script, or redirecting minicom to a file and then reading from the file in a different process will be a lot easier.

Comment: @ArnonZilca thank you again, I managed to do it without using minicom, what I did wrong was I wasn't reading the line needed via pyserial, pyserial is working, but I couldn't manage to use minicom inside the loop, but it is not necessary.