# How to convert python-to-arduino over serial code to python3-to-arduino over serial code?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

The code below used to work in spyder to communicate over serial with an arduino. In the console window of spyder, I would see lines of data being printed out:

78.7,77.9,100,80

78.7,77.9,100,80

78.7,77.9,100,80

78.7,77.9,100,80 ...

Data is from two temperature probes, a flowmeter, and the thermostat set temp.

I upgraded my Kubuntu 18.04 system to all things python3. Now, the code runs, but the spyder3 console window shows no visible characters, but scrolls blank lines. The rest of my python code for parsing and plotting this data doesn't work.

I've spent all day trying to fix this with no luck. I'm guessing it's a simple fix for someone with more experience than me.

The only difference between the old working code and the code below is that the print statements have parentheses added to remove the syntax error.

```
python

""" This code was originally copied from:
Listen to serial, return most recent numeric values
Lots of help from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093598/pyserial-how-to-read-last-line-sent-from-serial-device
"""

from threading import Thread

import time
import serial

last_received = ''
def receiving(ser):
    global last_received
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        buffer = buffer + ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if '\n' in buffer:
            lines = buffer.split('\n') # Guaranteed to have at least 2 entries
            last_received = lines[-2]
            #If the Arduino sends lots of empty lines, you'll lose the
            #last filled line, so you could make the above statement conditional
            #like so: if lines[-2]: last_received = lines[-2]
            buffer = lines[-1]


class SerialData(object):
    def __init__(self, init=50):
        try:
            self.ser = serial.Serial(
                port='/dev/ttyACM0',
                baudrate=9600,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                timeout=0.1,
                xonxoff=0,
                rtscts=0,
                interCharTimeout=None
            )
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            #no serial connection
            self.ser = None
        else:
            Thread(target=receiving, args=(self.ser,)).start()

    def next(self):
        if not self.ser:
            return '81.3,78.1,10.0,60.0,0' #100 #return anything so we can test when Arduino isn't connected
        #return a float value or try a few times until we get one
        for i in range(40):
            raw_line = last_received
            try:
               # return float(raw_line.strip())
                return str(raw_line.strip())
            except ValueError:
                print('bogus data',raw_line)
                time.sleep(.005)
        return 0.
    def __del__(self):
        if self.ser:
            self.ser.close()
    def write(self,val):
        self.ser.write(val)

if __name__=='__main__':
    s = SerialData()
    for i in range(500):
        time.sleep(.015)
        print( s.next())
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most significant differences between Python 2.x and 3.x is the way text strings are encoded. For Python 3.x everything is Unicode, as compared to ASCII for 2.x, so you just need to decode the raw bytes you read from the serial port:

```
buffer = buffer + ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode('utf-8')
```

**EDIT:** now you seem to have a different problem involving an exception. It looks like your port is open, to be sure you can change the way you handle the exception when you instantiate the port:

```
except serial.serialutil.SerialException as e: 
    print(e)
    self.ser = None
```

Once you know the error you should be able to handle it. Quite likely your port was not properly closed in an earlier session.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My continued research lead me to the difference between ascii and unicode. Making the .decode change now causes the:

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion- my continued efforts pointed to the difference between ascii and unicode. Substituting your .decode statement improves things some. Now, the 'if not self.ser' statement in the 'def next(self)' declaration is always true and the error default value '81.3,78.1,10.0,60.0,0' keeps getting printed by 'print(s.next())'

Comment: See update to print the exception and continue debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo! That last suggestion fixed the program and the python GUI interface I wrote for it is working with these corrections.

```
python

from threading import Thread
import time
import serial

last_received = ''
def receiving(ser):
    global last_received
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        buffer = buffer + ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode('utf-8')
        if '\n' in buffer:
            lines = buffer.split('\n') # Guaranteed to have at least 2 entries
            last_received = lines[-2]
            #If the Arduino sends lots of empty lines, you'll lose the
            #last filled line, so you could make the above statement conditional
            #like so: if lines[-2]: last_received = lines[-2]
            buffer = lines[-1]


class SerialData(object):
    def __init__(self, init=50):
        try:
            self.ser = serial.Serial(
                port='/dev/ttyACM1',
                baudrate=9600,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                timeout=0.1,
                xonxoff=0,
                rtscts=0,
                interCharTimeout=None
            )
        except serial.serialutil.SerialException as e: 
            print(e)
            #no serial connection
            self.ser = None
        else:
            Thread(target=receiving, args=(self.ser,)).start()

    def next(self):
       # if not self.ser:
       #     return '81.3,78.1,10.0,60.0,0' #100 #return anything so we can test when Arduino isn't connected
        #return a float value or try a few times until we get one
        for i in range(40):
            raw_line = last_received
            try:
               # return float(raw_line.strip())
                return str(raw_line.strip())
            except ValueError:
                print('bogus data',raw_line)
                time.sleep(.005)
        return 0.
    def __del__(self):
        if self.ser:
            self.ser.close()
    def write(self,val):
        self.ser.write(val)

if __name__=='__main__':
    s = SerialData()
    for i in range(500):
        time.sleep(.015)
        print (s.next())
```